# Knockout - binding an event with additional parameters

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of links that make up the navigation menu. I am trying to bind a tap event to the a tags.

This is the html

```
<a data-bind="event: { tap: $parent.menuClick.bind($index, $data.menuText, $data.menuValue) }">
```

And this is the javascript

```
this.menuClick = function (menuIndex, menuText, menuValue) {
    ....
}
```

This did not work. When I put in a breakpoint inside menuClick function, I see the parameter values are completely messed up.

menuIndex param has the menu item's text.
menuText param has the menu item's value
menuValue param has the knockout "$data" object.

Can someone please tell me how to pass the parameters correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to `bind` is the value to be used as `this` in the called function ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)). So you'll likely want the binding to be like this:

```
event: { tap: $parent.menuClick.bind($parent.menuClick, $index, $data.menuText, $data.menuValue) }
```

Alternately, you might be interested in the [Knockout.Punches plugin](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/) that allows you provide an expression to run for the event:

```
on.tap: $parent.menuClick($index, $data.menuText, $data.menuValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function is `this`.  So `menuText` ends up appearing as the `menuIndex` parameter and so on.  Pass in something else in its place (e.g., the view model).

```
<a data-bind="event: {
    tap: $parent.menuClick.bind($root, $index, $data.menuText, $data.menuValue)
}">...</a>
```

Comment: "it won't matter either way"  This is incorrect. The value specified in the `bind` call always takes precedence and won't be overridden when using `call` or `apply` (as Knockout does).

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted what I was seeing in my tests.